# Trouble listing filtered directory contents in Python: (need string, posix found)

Tags: python, regex, sys

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, since I took this method from another SO suggestion.

```
import os
import pathlib
import sys
import re

source = sys.argv[1]
directory = pathlib.Path(source).parent


res = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if re.search(r'.+_page_\d\.pdf', str(f))]
print res
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge_pdfs.py", line 12, in <module>
    res = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if re.search(r'.+_page_\d\.pdf', str(f))]
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, PosixPath found
```

Shouldn't the result of `listdir` be a list of strings?  How could I be getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a slash

```
directory = "{}/".format(directory)
```